# Data Validation Default Value

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

This is how it should work. In Data validation I have two values.

In C-4 if you enter "Employee" you can choose Discount Code.
But if you enter "Customer" the default Discount code is DC25.

However, I always get this error.

> OR expects boolean values. But '25 DISCOUNT' is a text and cannot be coerced to a boolean.

Can someone help me, please? This is the formula I'm using

```
=IF(OR(TRIM(C4)=("Customer"),"25 DISCOUNT"),IF(TRIM(C4)=LEFT("Employee"), VLOOKUP(TRIM(G6),J:K,2,false),  ""))
```

[MY SAMPLE SPREADSHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GB9rOiAZogcpzrEeuGOTOaPGWpmASk6QN3jHELJLm4o/copy)

**Data validation**

```
*---*----*---*----*----*--*
| DISCOUNT |              |
| CODE:    |              |
*---*--------*----*----*--*
| DC70     | 70 % DISCOUNT|
| DC25     | 25 % DISCOUNT|
*---*----*--------*----*--*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

- put a dropdown in **A** column selecting customer or employee

  [image: 0]
- in B1 cell paste this formula and drag down if needed:

  ```
  =IF(A1="Customer", "25% DISCOUNT", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1, I:J, 2, 0), "select code"))
  ```

  [image: 0]
- in C1 cell create dropdown from range E1:G1 like:

  [image: 0]
- in E1 cell use this formula and drag down if needed:

  ```
  =IF(A1="Employee", TRANSPOSE(FILTER(I$2:I, I$2:I<>"")), )
  ```

  [image: 0]
- when done you can hide E:G range:

  [image: 0]

---

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ghk17qsDVULPEVnZvVu1sOxmnLiIbdKn5Sxqpsh7mJE/copy)